# remove even numbers from a list

Tags: python, list

How can I remove even numbers from a list?

```
a = []
i = 0


while i < 10:
    c = int(raw_input('Enter an integer: '))
    a.append(c)
    i += 1  # this is the same as i = i + 1
    for i in a:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            a.remove(i)
print(a)
```

This keeps asking for numbers even after 10 have been entered

Comment: Well if you remove them, will you ever reach 10?  Try splitting this up into two parts.

Comment: Bad, bad, bad practice to reuse the same variable name for different variables. Call your loop-i someting more descriptive, like counter or similar. It's better to get used to this as soon as possible

Comment: You're resetting `i` by your second loop. You need to use a different variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not preventing the append if the number is even, instead of adding and then checking for removal?

```
a = []
counter = 0
while counter < 10:
    c = int(raw_input('Enter an integer: ')) 
    if c % 2 != 0:
        a.append(c)
    counter += 1
print(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

`i` is reassigned by the `for` statement. Use a different variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see how to 'filter' a list according to a predicate, here is an example:

```
a_without_even = filter(lambda x: x%2==1, a)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def removalDiffMethod(self, array):
    l=0
    r=len(array)
    while l<r:
        if array[l]%2==0:
            array[l:r] = array[l+1:r+1]
            r-=1
        else:
            l+=1
    return array[:r]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
your_dirty_list = [2,3,3,3,4,4,2,2,7,7,8] 
your_clean_list = [clean_dude for clean_dude in your_dirty_list if clean_dude % 2]
```

Out[]: [3, 3, 3, 7, 7]