# vim python prompting

Tags: vim, python-2.7, python-idle

This is a follow up question to [removing even numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800634/remove-even-numbers-from-a-list#).

Using the IDLE Python 2.7, the program prompts the user to enter numbers.  However, if I run the program from vim, it doesn't do this.

My vim does work with running python as long as the user doesn't need to input anything.  Is there a way to have vim prompt the user like the shell would?

Comment: How are you running it from vim? :!python myscript.py? or are you using something like ConqueTerm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement your script as a Vim script yes. Otherwise no.

You may try [ConqueTerm](http://code.google.com/p/conque/) or simply run your script in a separate terminal window.

Comment: How do I implement it as a Vim script?

Comment: You don't. It's hard and can't be explained here. Why don't you simply run it in another shell?

Comment: I downloaded conqueterm but there is one issue.  How do I turn off the red highlighting when I type now?